# Adding subview inside UICollectionView Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I am Working in `UICollectionView` added my Device Photos inside `UICollectionViewCell`, now I want to create subview inside my `UICollectionView`. Please suggest to me how to add `subview` inside `UICollectionViews`. Need any code or links.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewCell/contentView

Comment: Make me clear that you want to add subview in your UICollectionView Or in UICollectionViewCell

Comment: Yes. I dont think sub view is necessary. You can customize the collection view cell as you need exactly.

Comment: I want to add subview  in uicollectionViewcell

Comment: pl tell me how to customise the collectionviewcell

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding a subview is as simple as,

```
//Create subview    
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.collectionView.frame.size.width, 20)];
//Add
[collectionView addSubview:subview];
//Bring to front so that it does not get hidden by cells
[collectionView bringSubviewToFront:subview];
//This will shift collectionView content down by 20px at top
[collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(subview.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0)];
```

The above code will add a subview at top of collectionView. Is this what you are looking for? If not please provide more details in your question.

Comment: the inset space will be inserted at the top above subview (iOS 8)

Comment: @jAckOdE any idea how to do this on iOS8?

Comment: Add view to your collection view, and observe the content offset of the collection view and update your subview frame accordingly

Comment: @jAckOdE can you share sample code for content offset